# Mule : javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: ssl, mule

I have a mule project which uses outbound connection to my local tomcat server over HTTPS (TLS) using self signed cert. When I execute the flow, I get following exception

**Mule HTTP Connector**

```
<http:request-config name="SP2" host="my_fqdn" port="38443" doc:name="SP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" >
    <tls:context>
        <tls:trust-store path="/temp/temp1.keystore.jks" password="changeit" type="jks"/>
    </tls:context>
</http:request-config>
```

**Error From Mule Flow**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.domain.request.ClientConnection.getClientCertificate(ClientConnection.java:67) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpRequestToMuleEvent.transform(HttpRequestToMuleEvent.java:63) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener.createEvent(DefaultHttpListener.java:165) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener.access$000(DefaultHttpListener.java:39) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:124) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
```

Normally this means that my trust store is not set correctly. In my case, I have the trust store setup in the Mule's TLS context. As I am still getting the error, I am thinking that Mule is somehow not honoring my TLS context setup.

Additionally, I setup a test program inside the Anypoint Studio in the same project as where my Mule flow was executing.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/temp/temp1.keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", KeyStore.getDefaultType());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");

SocketFactory sslContext = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.createSocket("my_fqdn",38443);
SSLSession sslSession = sslSocket.getSession();
sslSession.getPeerCertificates();
```

In the above mentioned Java code, if I were to not set the trust store properly, I get the "peer not authenticated" error. However when I set the trust store as mentioned then the program executes without any error. Finally I tried passing the trust store as JVM args but that also did not work.

So I am clueless about why mule is acting this way. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What mule version are you using? Try adding the trust store file as an application resource.

Comment: Mule 3.7.2. I tried keeping the truststore inside the project as well but that didnt help.

Comment: The stack trace you are showing puts the error on a ```http-listener``` but the config is for a ```http-request```. What does the listener config look like?

Comment: I have incoming HTTP listener as well. Here is the listener config

`<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="my_fqdn" port="28443" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="/temp/temp1.keystore.jks" password="changeit" keyPassword="changeit"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:listener-config>`

When I used HTTPS listener and HTTP as outgoing, my setup worked. When I used HTTPS listener and HTTPS as outgoing, I started getting the mentioned error.

Comment: On further debugging, I found that the original stacktrace reported by me is actually just debug warning from HTTP listener and not the root cause of the problem. The root error message is

**java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed**

I found [link](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/145) on web but dont know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule 3.7.2 uses SSLV2Hello by default. The Tomcat connector was closing connection when it received SSLV2Hello. I fixed the issue by modifying the tomcat connector as following, mainly around sslEnabledProtocols list.

```
<Connector port="38443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
 maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
 keystoreFile="/tmp/temp1.keystore.jks" 
 keystorePass="changeit"  
 sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv2Hello"/>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, that is not a Mule 3.7.2 issue but a Anypoint Studio issue. When running in mule standalone SSLv2Hello is disabled so that shouldn't happen. The Studio team is already working on fixing the problem.